# elasticsearch split index error,routing shards must be a multiple of the target shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to split index `nozomi-trace-log`(5 shards,`number_of_routing_shards` not set)  into target `nozomi-log-thomas` with 10 shards.
According to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-split-index.html#_preparing_an_index_for_splitting),first i issued a commmand that set `number_of_routing_shards` to 20 for the source index:

```
PUT /nozomi-trace-log/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "index.number_of_routing_shards" : 20 
    }
}
```

check the result:

```
{
  "nozomi-trace-log": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "nozomi-trace-log",
        "creation_date": "1594180347628",
        "unassigned": {
          "node_left": {
            "delayed_timeout": "5m"
          }
        },
        "number_of_routing_shards": "20",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "Yal04AcQRUyZQIjrUGwTGw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then i issue `_split` command,but it gave an error:

```
POST nozomi-trace-log/_split/nozomi-log-thomas
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 10
  }
}
```

error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[***][**.**.**.**:9300][indices:admin/resize]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "the number of routing shards [5] must be a multiple of the target shards [10]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

The error appears to indicate that `number_of_routing_shards` of the source index is 5, but the first command has already set `number_of_routing_shards` to 20.So where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you have linked, the index is created with a specific number of routing shards, while in your example you are modifying the setting of an existing index.

At the beginning of the linked docs it is stated clearly that in the version you are using (6.2):

> The _split API requires the source index to be created with a specific number_of_routing_shards in order to be split in the future. This requirement has been removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.

This means that in the version 6.x of Elasticsearch, you have to create an index with the "right" number of routing shards before creating it. To this extent consider the use of index-templates with the desired settings.

(Moreover: In the question you forgot the step of making the source index read-only)

### Possible Solution (REINDEX)

So, that's being said, you could give the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-reindex.html) a try.

You can optionally make the source index read-only to avoid conflicts:

```json
PUT /nozomi-trace-log/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.blocks.write": true 
  }
}
```

First create the target index with the right settings:

```json
PUT nozomi-log-thomas
{
  "settings": {
       "index.number_of_shards": 10
   }
}
```

Then reindex the source index into the target index

```json
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "nozomi-trace-log"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "nozomi-log-thomas"
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue with the split api even though my index was originally created on elastic 7.10